# image-charts url is not respecting chds

Tags: image-charts

### chds = 0,1800

https://image-charts.com/chart?chd=a%3A2060%2C971%2C849&chds=0,1800&chs=700x100&cht=bvg

[image: chds 0,1800 chart with lower bar]

### chds = 0,2000

https://image-charts.com/chart?chd=a%3A2060%2C971%2C849&chds=0,2000&chs=700x100&cht=bvg

[image: chds 0,2000 with higher bar]

So `chds = 0,1800` has a lower bar than `chds = 0,2000` when I expect the opposite. With `chds = 0,1800` I expect the bar to take up the whole image since 2060 is more than 1800.

Docs: https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/chart-axis/

Answer (score 0):

Image-Charts founder here :)

As per our documentation, chds as you want to use it works with `chd=t:` (like in Google Image Charts). `chds` is not necessary with `chd=a:`.

With `chd=t:` `chds` work as expected:

## chds=0,1800&chd=t:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chd=t:2060,971,849&chds=0,1800&chs=700x100&cht=bvg
```

[image]

## chds=0,2000&chd=t:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chd=t:2060,971,849&chds=0,2000&chs=700x100&cht=bvg
```

[image]